# My wife used this computer for her Gmail work email and no longer works there. I can't log her out

Tags: google-chrome

My wife used this computer for her Gmail work email and no longer works there.  I can't log her out since her user name and password have been deleted.

When I bring up a new window, it lists the Google Store, Google Search , YouTube and Gmail with her old work email in the upper right.  I can't click on it to do anything with it.

I can sign in to my Gmail account, but some of the Extensions I'm trying to use aren't working.  When I go into Settings, "Sign In" says "Error signing in.  Sign in again."

I've done that numerous times, but the same results.  The "Disconnect your Google account" is greyed out.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Works where???? Just delete the profile

Comment: What is it you want to do? There is no question here.

Comment: He wants to either sign out or get his credentials back.

Comment: What is the question you're asking?

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall chrome?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the grey tool close to the adress-bar. Select "settings" and "Sign Out Of Chrome" - Then you go to logg/history and click "Delete all data"- or something. Now you will get a new window up, delete all the cookies or everything :-) Good luck.

Comment: Can you give more detailed steps, for more information on answering questions please see [answer]

Comment: This answer is clear...